# Как завернуть метод поиска файла в блок try-catch?

Tags: java

Написал метод, который ищет файл по заданному пути и имени файла. Как можно завернуть в блок try-catch ошибку FileNotFoundException? Попробовал завернуть и пишет ошибку:

```
Exception 'java.io.FileNotFoundException' is never thrown in the corresponding try block
```

Вот сам код:

```
public static boolean findFile(String path, String filename) throws FileNotFoundException {
    boolean fileExists = false;

        File f = new File(path);
        File[] files = f.listFiles();
        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            if (files[i].toString().equals(path + "\\" + filename) && files[i].isFile()) {
                fileExists = true;
                System.out.println("Файл найден");
                return fileExists;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Файл не найден, проверьте правильность ввода пути и названия файла");
            }
        }
        return fileExists;
}
```

Comment: Какой участок кода вы завернули в try/catch? Какая операция может бросить это исключение? Ни одна из функций `java.io.File` не бросает `FileNotFoundException`. Если вы просто хотите проверить существует ли файл используйте метод `exists` в классе `File`.

Answer (score -1):

Выражение:
f.listFiles() вернет null если файла  f нет.

Таким образом исключение FileNotFoundException не может быть выброшено. А будет выброшено NUllPointerException в строке files.length

Если вы хотите обработать эту ситуацию добавьте проверку на null.

```
File[] files = f.listFiles();
if(files == null) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]